# Undefined reference to `registerrpc'

Tags: c, linux, rpc

I have this simple server that has to register a procedure to make it available over RPC. here is my server.c:

```
#include <rpc/rpc.h>
int * p_double(int n){
    static int d;
    d = 2 * n;
    return &d;
}
int main(){
    registerrpc(0x22222222, 1, 1, p_double, xdr_int, xdr_int );
    svc_run();
    return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile it i get these errors :

```
> gcc -o s server.c
/tmp/ccd0Roxs.o: In function `main':
server.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to `registerrpc'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What I got from that is that it cannot find `registerrpc` anywhere or at least in `rpc/rpc.h`

I am using Ubuntu 12.04, and another student in my class got it to work by installing `portmap` So I tried doing the same thing. Unfortunately this did not help with anything.

(I am not sure if this belongs here though, sorry)

Comment: If you compile with more warnings (add `-Wall` to the options), does it also warn that `registerrpc` was implicitly declared?

Comment: yes it does. I did not add it because I thought `server.c:(.text+0x47): undefined reference to 'registerrpc'` to be even more expressive

Comment: Well, since it was implicitly declared, it's not defined in `rpc/rpc.h`. Finding the correct _header_ for it might go a long way toward finding the correct library. (Or it's possible that the function is deprecated and you're supposed to use some other function from that header, I don't really know about rpc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rpc header you are using does not define a `registerrpc` function. I believe you are probably following a guide based on another operating system (or possibly an older version). I think the best solution would be to find a guide for doing the same thing with the functions in your `rpc/rpc.h`.

However, on Ubuntu it seems you can install an alternative RPC library with `apt-get install libtirpc-dev`, and then compile with the options:

```
gcc -o server -I /usr/include/tirpc server.c -l tirpc
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to link with the RPC library, `librpc`:

```
$ gcc -Wall -lrpc server.c -o server
```

Comment: It says `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lrpc`

Comment: Where did you install your RPC headers and libraries ?

Comment: Actually I did not install any headers. I thought they came with the OS.

Comment: Try `gcc -Wall -lrpcsvcs ...` instead of `gcc -Wall -lrpc ...` and if that doesn't work then do a `find /usr /opt -name librpc\*` to see where the RPC library is and what it's called.

Comment: The only result I got is : `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librpcsvc.a`

Comment: OK - so try `gcc -Wall -lrpcsvc server.c -o server`

Comment: It still says that it cannot find a reference to `registerrpc`. but when I use @Arkku's solution it actually seems to recognize the function. Thank yoy

Comment: OK - not sure why it's not working for you, but go with @Arkku's solution if that works.

Comment: I found this when compiling with legacy glibc code (glibc needs to be compiled --enable-obsolete-rpc) instead of [libtirpc](http://git.linux-nfs.org/?p=steved/libtirpc.git;a=summary). It looks like [glibc implement it](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sunrpc/svc_simple.c;h=2f2595c0ffe14ded98656eaa731c6d71ccbb6f61;hb=HEAD#l62), but does not export it :(. BTW good reading for RPC in glibc vs. libtirpc: https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Glibc_2.26_porting_notes/RPC_implementation

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like you referenced the library that contains registerrpc

Comment: Here in this link they say registerrpc belongs in rpc/rpc.h http://linux.die.net/man/3/registerrpc

Comment: That is correct, the header is there, but the actual library that the header references is not in your call to gcc. If you look at the following link it shows how to link to the library containing registerrpc http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_17.html

Comment: I understand. What you are saying is that I need to link to the rpc library ? do you know where I could find it ?

Comment: I don't have it installed on my system, but I suspect it is called librpclib.a, so I would try doing an ls against /usr/lib/librpclib.a, if it comes back with a hit, then add the full path to that library (/usr/lib/librpclib.a) to your gcc call and you should be good.